# VB6 Require some help with looping

Tags: c++, vb6

I am trying to convert a source from C++ to vb6:

C++:

```
static double mdArray[3][3];
static double mdArray2[3][3];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
  double sum = 0;

  for(k = 0; k < 3; k++)
  sum = sum + mdArray[k][i] * mdArray[k][k];

  mdArray2[i][j] = sum
}
```

VB6:

```
dim mdArray(0 to 2, 0 to 2) as integer
dim mdArray2(0 to 2, 0 to 2) as integer

for i = 0 to 2
for j = 0 to 2

dim a as double
sum = 0

  for k = 0 to 2 
  sum = sum + mdArray(k,i) * mdArray(k,j)

  mdArray2(i,j) = sum
  Next

Next
Next
```

Will the vb6 version yield the same result as the C++ version? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Did you even bother to *try* it? Here's the errors I could spot:

1. You declare your arrays with the wrong datatype
2. You're declaring `a` instead of `sum` for some reason
3. You have `mdArray(k, j)` instead of `mdArray(k, k)`
4. Your innermost `Next` statement should be before `mdArray2(i,j) = sum`, not after it.

Comment: +1 And it's easy to try it. Visual C++ express edition is free. Presumably you have VB6 (otherwise there's not much point in the exercise)

Answer (score 3):

> Will the vb6 version yield the same result as the C++ version?

Did you try it?

Your arrays are declared as `double` in C++ but `Integer` in  VB6. Apart from that, the codes look pretty identical, except for the innermost loop (using proper indentation would have prevented this mistake easily!):

```
for k = 0 to 2 
  sum = sum + mdArray(k,i) * mdArray(k,j)
Next
mdArray2(i,j) = sum
```

The `dArray2(i,j) = sum` line belongs *outside* the loop.